# How do I animate react-bootstrap progress bar from 0 to N on page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am using the react-bootstrap ui library for the progress bar. I want it to animate the progress bar from 0 to 70 on page load.

How do I achieve it?

Here is the code

**Component.js**

```
<ProgressBar
        animated
        now={70}
        className="progress-bar"
      />
```

**Component.style**

```
.progress-bar {
  width: 400px;
}
```

**Expected OutPut:** It should animate from 0 to 70 on page load.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `animate` property doesn't animate the progress, but animates the **stripes** on the progress bar.

From the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/progress/#progress-bar-props):

`Animate's the stripes from right to left`

What you need is a timer that updates the `now` property. Probably something like this:

```
const MyComp = () => {
 const [progressNow, setProgressNow] = useState(0)

 const updateProgressNowHandler = setInterval(() => {
  if (progressNow >= 70 ){
   setProgressNow(70)
   clearInterval(updateProgressNowHandler)
  }
  setProgressNow(s => s+1)
 }, 50)

 return 
  <ProgressBar
        animated
        now={progressNow}
        className="progress-bar"
      />
}
```

This is by no means production ready.

You need to make sure that you clear the interval when the component unmounts.

If there is a chance that the component will be re-rendered (which most likely will happen) you need to keep track of the progress already made and start with the counter from the last value.